# How can I bind the single LINQ object to ASP.NET Repeater Control

Tags: c#, linq, data-binding, repeater

Below is the code snippet which get single record from the database and bind to repeater data source. But when the page render it throws an error

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var movie= context.movies.GetMovie();

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Repeater1.DataSource = movie.;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }

        }
```

Error Message:

```
An invalid data source is being used for Repeater1. A valid data source must implement either IListSource or IEnumerable.
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it an array:

```
Repeater1.DataSource = new[]{ movie };
```

But if you always show just a single record i would use a `FormView` or `DetailsView` instead.

Have a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227992(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You could hack it doing like `Repeater1.DataSource = new List<Movie>() { movie };`

Comment: Thank you very much. That's work. The reason for using repeater for a  because I wan to have custom html markup on the page. I found out other data controls produce tables when they render. I want to have custom defined markup appear on the view source. Do you have better suggestion?

Comment: @user2866746: as mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21158893/284240) you can use a `FormView` or `DetailsView` instead. The difference is that the `DetailsView` produces the (undesired) tabular layout whereas the `FormView` gives you full control. You create a template that contains controls to display individual fields from the record similar to the repeater.

Comment: I would probably used a FormView or DetailsView like suggested by @TimSchmelter, or implemented a custom view for viewing the details.

Comment: If I use form view Can I directly bind a single linq object to it's data source?

Comment: @user2866746: No, the `DataSource` property of every databound `WebControl` in ASP.NET needs to implement either `IListSource` or `IEnumerable` even if it displays just a single record. That's illogical but not a problem because you can use our workarounds.